# One CPU core maxes and PC crashes seconds later (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: dual-boot, freeze, crash, cpu

My Ubuntu 22.04 crashes/freezes when I launch a non-native app, like Firefox or Chrome. Terminal and system monitor seems to be fine. Before it crashes, one of the CPU cores will max out to 100% for 10~15 seconds before everything freezes. It's not always the same CPU core that maxes out; it switches every so often if it hasn't crashed yet. I have to hold the power button to shut off my laptop. I have observed that, after the freeze, the lights still dim after 10 minutes of not touching the computer, and lights up again when I press a button, but everything is still frozen in place. Does this mean it's still running somehow?

I am currently using a MSI Prestige 15 laptop that was originally installed with Windows. I reinstalled Ubuntu twice (dual boot), but the same exact problem remains. Is there anything I can run to figure out what the problem is? I'm pretty new to this, I apologize if I haven't given enough information.

Here are the logs from syslog that seems to have issues: (it goes on repeat afterwards)

```
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD gvfsd[1709]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping PipeWire Media Session Manager...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping Tracker file system data miner...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping flatpak document portal service...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: dbus.service: Killing process 1857 (gdbus) with signal SIGKILL.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1]: run-user-127-gvfs.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped PipeWire Media Session Manager.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: xdg-document-portal.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=20/n/a
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: xdg-permission-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopping PipeWire Multimedia Service...
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-fs-3[1767]: OK
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Stopped Tracker file system data miner.
Jul  1 10:10:23 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD systemd[1668]: Removed slice User Background Tasks Slice.
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_new_for_uri: assertion 'uri != NULL' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_new_for_uri: assertion 'uri != NULL' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_new_for_uri: assertion 'uri != NULL' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_new_for_uri: assertion 'uri != NULL' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: message repeated 2 times: [ g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed]
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_object_ref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_hash: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed
Jul  1 10:10:26 zane-Prestige-15-A12UD tracker-miner-f[2335]: message repeated 2 times: [ g_file_equal: assertion 'G_IS_FILE (file1)' failed]
```

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: what specific logs should I look at? var/crash or var/logs?

Comment: Were I in your shoes, I would look at both. And `journalctl` too. Yes, there's a lot to wade through. But you know what times those events occurred. Reading logs is a learned skill, so take your time and treat this as a learning opportunity, not a chore.

Comment: okay, thank you! I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled secure boot "support" through BIOS and reinstalled, which solved my problem.